# passing arguments @factory from testng.xml

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to pass the parameter to my factory class through testNg.xml. Can you please guide me on how I can do that?

I have tried as below but no luck.

```
@Factory
@Parameters ({"function"})   // am passing the function parameter from testng.xml
public object[][] testFactory(String function) {
....
}
```

Comment: How are you ascertaining that this is not working?  Parameters with factory do work. Give more data for someone to help you.